# Why is java considered a high performance language?

Tags: java, c, performance

Being a Java Developer, I've often read and heard that Java is considered a high-performance language[1]. So far for me as a programer, I have never had to worry about the performance of my Java applications simply because they did little tasks that just don't take long on modern computer hardware. As user, however, I've had to worry about the performance of Java. For instance, Minecraft (a pix game that looks old school) and RuneScape (a game that doesn't have good graphics, either) run significantly slower on my hardware [2] than any C(++) game with better graphics. Even HTML5 Games are way quicker than Java.
So why is Java considered a high-performance language (along with C) if end users experience worse performance? I know the seed depends on quality of the code but I think both games I've mentioned above are popular, well maintained games that are owned by profit orientated organizations that put a lot of effort in improving performance.

---

[1]: For instance:

> "Take for example Smalltalk, Lisp, Java and C++. All of them are, or
>   have at one point been, the language of choice for high-performance
>   code. All of them have huge amounts of engineering and research
>   man-centuries expended on them to make them fast." https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200486/1493365

[2]: I have to note that my PC doesn't have a GPU, it's included in my CPU. But Java is know by all end-user I know as a "slow" language.

Comment: By high-performance, perhaps they are referring to its ease of implementation across multiple platforms.

Comment: Java haven't been considered "slow" for at least a decade. Since SUN's HotSpot compiler most Java runtimes today recompiles the Java VM code to native code. The only people who consider Java slow are people who either don't use Java but has "heard" that it's slow, or detractors who actively dislike Java and help spread these rumors.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've heard about it but still, why does it have less FPS than other games? And why is eclipse slower than other IDEs like xcode?

Comment: http://www.cinnober.com/sites/default/files/news/The-benefits-of-Java-white-paper-1.pdf read this book to know that

Comment: I can write a game in assembler that has lower FPS than any Java game you could think of. Besides, FPS is a red herring, do you really need more FPS than what your monitor is capable of? You won't see the extra frames anyway.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg As I've mentioned above, it depends on the code. But why does Minecraft (which is optimized by a company that really needs the game to work as smoothly as possible) run with about 15-20 FPS while other games which have about the same graphics run with 50+? Most endusers (especially gamer) dislike Java because the performance isn't equal to C games or cross-platform HTML5 games.

Comment: You might have a look at http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/java.php

Comment: @Matt3o12 - eclipse is slow. try intellij IDEA. lightning fast, written in java.

Comment: There's always been a fear of "bytecode" and JVM/JIT... and some purists don't believe in requiring end-user runtimes, (.NET  with the CLR as another example), as these installers like to jam up non-centralized systems with "Updaters" and whatnot. Though people scoff at the idea of lowlevel systems programming like bootloaders, kernels, and drivers in Java, it's not completely crazy/

Comment: @JoachimPileborg FPS is not a red herring - it indicates how much more work the game could do before becoming noticeably slow.

Comment: @Matt3o12 I've heard the current Minecraft snapshots have >10-fold increases in FPS. You might want to rethink the assumption that Minecraft was optimized.